# Remote tests case execution on ALM-UFT, tests fails because of permissions

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm

I am currently working with ALM and Unified Functional Testing. I have a set of tests that are currently "Passed" when I execute its directly from UFT, but when I run them from ALM, it throws an error and make the test fail :

```
Run Error: You do not have the required permissions to execute this action.
Function file: [ALM\Resources] Resources\Release VXXRYY\Libraries\Report.qfl
Line (91): "        attachment.Post()"
```

The error is thrown by a line :

```
attachment.Post
```

This function is only supposed to capture screenshots of the application under test. And most of the time, it works fine BUT when it fails the image file is created but without any content (0 KB), and the message above is displayed in report :

[image: example]

Also I do not know if that is related but I also have some fails due to :

```
Run Error:
Invalid server response
Function file: [ALM\Resources] Resources\Release VXXRYY\Libraries\Report.qfl
Line (68): "        myStepList.Post".
```

I really do not see the source of the problem... Any help is welcomed !
Tell me if in any case you need more informations,

Thank you

Comment: As the error report, you do not have permission to create the post. "Run Error: You do not have the required permissions to execute this action." My question: is the user you are using always the same with full rights? Or is the report and the attachment done by different users?

Comment: The report is made by only one user. That's why it's strange, why would it work for one screenshot and then crash for the next one...

Comment: How do you use the ALM? I mean: do you send REST message by using the REST API? Is it always failing by the ALM usage?

Comment: Make Sure that you have TDADmin privilage added to your ALM ID. That should resolve your problem.